# Add database connections on the fly, instead of defining them in settings.php

Tags: 8, database, migrations

> I am trying to add DB Information on the fly, instead of defining in
>   settings.php

I am adding connection on module install

```
$other_database = array(
  'database' => 'pantheon',
  'username' => 'pantheon',
  'password' => 'password',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'dbserver.dfssg.drush.in',
  'port' => '4587',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql', 
);
Database::addConnectionInfo('legacy', 'default', $other_database);
```

and trying to use 'legacy' key with the migration file

```
source:
  plugin: d8_entity
  key: legacy
  entity_type: node
  bundle: article
```

But, I getting an error

```
 The specified database connection is not defined: legacy
```

Is I am missing something?

Comment: When you add a connection “on-the-fly” it only persists for that request. So you have to add it again on each request, which isn’t conceptually compatible with doing it on module install. You might be able to hack something to work inside a module file, but really this information belongs in settings.php, or a file included from settings.php

Comment: ohh, Thanks @Clive